# Measuring time in an if statement c++

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

Well... since 2 days ago I have been working on a project which records the clicks you make and repeats that over and over(just like a bot), the problem is at the moment that is recording the time between clicks because when measuring time with the "**steady_clock::now**" on a if statement, it is only declared in the if statement and if I try to make it a global variable with a NULL value, the compiler throws me an error because the "**auto**" variable type has to have a default value.

```
#include<chrono>

using namespace std::chrono;

auto start = NULL; //this is an error

int main()
{
     if (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON))
    {
        auto start = steady_clock::now();
    }
     else if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON))
    {
        auto end = steady_clock::now();

        std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = end - start;   //here the compiler throws me an error because start is not declared
    }

}
```

I will really appreciate if someone responds my question.

Sorry for my english...

Comment: you set up `start` in the other if path, you code simply doesnt make sense. Read it to yourself. You never set start and end , you only set one or the other

Comment: You can't use `auto` for this: you'll need to just declare the actual object. Alternatively, you can move the declaration of `start` outside the `if`, then set it inside as well. I've written this as a comment because it looks as if once you fix this your code is going to suffer from other problems anyway

Comment: @Tas, why cant auto be used here? Seems like a scope issue not an auto issue

Comment: I meant they'll need to default construct the actual object, or they can use `auto` above the `if` statement. But then I only have C++03 so I could be 100% wrong :)

Comment: ooo - I just noticed you have 2 things called start. Dont do that. Its really not clear what calculation you want to do

Answer (score 0):

This is where [`decltype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) is useful:

```
decltype(steady_clock::now()) start;
// ...
start = steady_clock::now();
```

It is the type of the expression inside the parenthesis.

Comment: Of course, you can also just look up the type of the return value and make it explicit.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are trying to set up "start" twice and are also trying to use auto in an incorrect manner. What is the compiler supposed to assume when it sees **auto start = NULL** ? So kindly look up how it used.

Meanwhile,I think what you are looking for is something like this :

```
#include<chrono>

std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start; // You can mention the type of start and end explicitly,.
std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end;

int main()
{
    if (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON))
    {
        start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    }
    else // don't think you needed an else-if here.
    {
        end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed = end - start; 
    }
}
```